# Why function imported from custom made module behaves differently while it is working in JSfiddle?

Tags: node.js, lodash

I have 2 files index.js and sort.js.

index.js file contains a variable "x" whose value is an array of objects of English words. Each object contains a "pos" property which is again an array, whose value can be n, v, adj, adv (contains at least one values)

sort.js contains a function which takes variable "x" as its parameter. Then it arranges words in such a way that each pos value becomes a separate array inside the main array.

**The code is working in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jtkm65us/1/), but getting an empty array as an output in my project**. I have tried the different exporting method in sort.js file like module.exports etc.

*Note: I am using lodash as a dependency.*

Here is the code of both the files:

index.js

```
const _ = require("lodash");
const { sortByPos } = require("../lib/sort");

/* 
 Some extra code here
*/

let x = [
    {
      word: "music",
      pos: ["n"],
      first: "m",
      wordCount: 1,
      len: 5
    },
    {
      word: "scale",
      pos: ["n", "v"],
      first: "s",
      wordCount: 1,
      len: 5
    },
    {
      word: "beats",
      pos: ["n"],
      first: "b",
      wordCount: 1,
      len: 5
    },
    {
      word: "surmount",
      pos: ["v"],
      first: "s",
      wordCount: 1,
      len: 8
    },
    {
      word: "euphony",
      pos: ["n", "adv"],
      first: "e",
      wordCount: 1,
      len: 7
    },
    {
      word: "trounce",
      pos: ["adj", "v"],
      first: "t",
      wordCount: 1,
      len: 7
    }
  ];

  console.log(sortByPos(x))
```

sort.js

```
const _ = require("lodash");
exports.sortByPos = words => {
 return _.reduce(
 words,
 (result, obj) => {
   _.forEach(obj.pos, el => (result[el] || (result[el] = [])).push(obj));
   return result;
 },
 []
 );
};
```

---

Update: Code is not working properly in JSFiddle also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reduce accumulator (`result`) is an array, but you assign non numeric keys to it. Instead use an object as the accumulator, and if you need an array, use `_.values()` or `Object.values()` to convert it to an array:

```js
const sortByPos = words => {
  return _.reduce(
    words,
    (result, obj) => {
      _.forEach(obj.pos, el => (result[el] || (result[el] = [])).push(obj));
      return result;
    }, {}
  );
};

let x = [{"word":"music","pos":["n"],"first":"m","wordCount":1,"len":5},{"word":"scale","pos":["n","v"],"first":"s","wordCount":1,"len":5},{"word":"beats","pos":["n"],"first":"b","wordCount":1,"len":5},{"word":"surmount","pos":["v"],"first":"s","wordCount":1,"len":8},{"word":"euphony","pos":["n","adv"],"first":"e","wordCount":1,"len":7},{"word":"trounce","pos":["adj","v"],"first":"t","wordCount":1,"len":7}];

console.log(sortByPos(x)) // an object of arrays

console.log(_.values(sortByPos(x))) // an array of arrays
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's not working in the fiddle. Arrays are objects, and you can add more properties to an array. However, when you try to iterate it as an array, the add properties are not included. You can see in the fiddle, that the length of the array is 0.